# A better way to say "masters of translation"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, translation

What is the best and native way to use words **master** and **translators** to denote a "group of highly skilled translators"?
I am stuck with initial "M" letter, as it is used in the brand name and logo, so the first word has to start with "M" and I cannot use a simple option like "expert translators"...

`Masters of translation` seems to be misleading, as if referring to an academic degree.

So far, I thought of using adjectives:

1) `master translators`,

2) `masterful translators`,

...and similar looking words:

3) `maestros of translation`,

4) `translation meisters`.

Please, vote or tell, which is the better option.

Comment: Grammatically speaking, the closest equivalent to *expert translators* is *master translators*.

Comment: Another synonym beginning with "m" is *maven*, but I agree that *master translators* is the nicest-sounding suggestion.

Comment: What's wrong with "cunning linguist"?

Comment: I changed my mind; I like *maven* better than *master* now that I've mulled it over for a few minutes.

Comment: @JasonBassford I thought of "master translators", but hesitated in doubt because of IT terms like *master hdd* and *slave hdd*, which made be thinking of a main group of translators and a secondary group of translators; though I understand, It looks like my own association because of many years in IT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually say *none* of your examples are particularly idiomatic, and I would personally just say:

> Highly skilled translators.

My reason is that "expert" refers to someone who is a master (having complete mastery) of a particular field, and while translation is a field of work it is fairly unique in that you could be skilled in just 2 or 3 different languages and be considered "highly skilled" even though there are many hundreds of more languages in the world you could learn. Do you become an "expert" in translation when you are fluent in two languages? Or three? Or two hundred? It strikes me as a field where the word "expert" just doesn't fit.

Saying someone is "highly skilled" suggests that they are as skilled as they possibly can be *for the task at hand* or *for the work they already do*. Someone who is "highly skilled" at translation between English and French would not necessarily be any use translating to and from Greek, so for such a task you would seek someone skilled in that language rather than "a translation expert".

If you need a brand name with the initials "MT" why don't you choose another kind of superlative such as:

- Magnificent
- Marvellous
- Matchless
- Masterly (meaning "highly skilled", rather than *the* master)
- Masterful (again, does not mean "master" but having the qualities to be one)

Comment: Thanks! "masterly translators" will be the closest match to my needs, I think

Comment: though over and over about using "experts in translation" as a subtitle or slogan near the brand name, but your paragraph lead me to a question: does it really refer to a narrow field or temporary assignment, like, e.g. being a *court expert* rather than obtaining an advantage over peers due to experience (e.g. a translator professionally working long-term with one pair of languages)?